# Removing search part of a url

Tags: javascript

I am getting url of a anchor object like `document.links[0].href`. I want to remove the search part("Part which comes after '?' symbol") from this string. I know that I can use regex for this. Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = //my string
a = a.substr(0, a.indexOf('?'));
```

Just get the substring up until the first `?`; if for some reason you have 2 `?`, the second one is probably in the query path and will be removed anyway...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split it on the "?" character.

```
var url = document.links[0].href;
var base = url.split("?")[0];
```

should be faster but of course you could run into trouble if you have for some reason two ?'s in the url.

Comment: This will work. But I am very much concerned about performance. I will have to process hundreds of links before 600 ms. Already it takes around 550 ms. So doing this will be a trouble.

Comment: @Selvaraj M A — Have you benchmarked this? I suspect you'll find that most of that time is spent hitting the DOM to get the strings rather then the string processing itself.

Answer (score -1):

you can find search part using this:

```
document.location.search
```

and then replace it from document.location.href or use document.location.host and document.location.pathname for your purpose

Comment: This wont work. Because I am getting the url from a anchor object(Which is a string). Not from document.